# How to access Nested Object with Map in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm quite new to react JS, I need to access the selected nested object using the map method in reactJS. I need the output as below screenshot.please someone help me on this.

[image]

**DishdetailComponent.js | File**

```
import {
    Card,
    CardImg,
    CardImgOverlay,
    CardText,
    CardBody,
    CardTitle
} from 'reactstrap';

class DishDetail  extends Component{
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedDish: null
        }
    };

    onDishSelect(dish){
        this.setState({selectedDish: dish})
    }

    renderDish(dish) {
        if (dish != null)
            return(
                <Card>
                    <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            );
        else
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
    }

    renderComments(dish){
        if (dish != null)
            return(
                <Card key={dish.comments.id}
                  onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Comments</CardTitle>
                      <CardText key={dish.comments.id}>{dish.comments.map((sup)=> sup.comment)}</CardText>
                      <CardText>{dish.comments.map((sup)=> sup.author)}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            );
        else
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
    }

    render() {
        const menu = this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
                <div  className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card key={dish.id}
                  onClick={() => this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                  <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                      <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
              </div>
            );
        });

        return (
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {menu}
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div  className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)}
              </div>
              <div  className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                {this.renderComments(this.state.selectedDish)}
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        );
    }
}

export default  DishDetail;
```

**dishes.js | File**

```
    [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]                        },
        {
        id: 1,
        name:'Zucchipakoda',
        image: 'assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label:'',
        price:'1.99',
        description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        name:'Vadonut',
        image: 'assets/images/vadonut.png',
        category: 'appetizer',
        label:'New',
        price:'1.99',
        description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        id: 3,
        name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
        image: 'assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
        category: 'dessert',
        label:'',
        price:'2.99',
        description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 2,
            rating: 3,
            comment: "Eat it, just eat it!",
            author: "Michael Jaikishan",
            date: "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 3,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
            author: "Ringo Starry",
            date: "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 4,
            rating: 2,
            comment: "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
            author: "25 Cent",
            date: "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
        ]
        }
    ];
```

**App.js | File**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap';

import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './components/DishdetailComponent';

import { DISHES } from './shared/dishes';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dishes: DISHES
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <Navbar dark color="primary">
            <div className="container">
              <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
            </div>
        </Navbar>
        <DishDetail dishes={this.state.dishes}/>
        {/* <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

to have better understand please refer below link

https://noorzee.github.io/confusion/

Comment: Can you explain where in your code things are *not* working for you?

Comment: Can you please explain where in the code you need the help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you want to show all comments for each product.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-bogdan-c609v?file=/src/App.js)

### Explanation

Given the fact that comments is an array, you assumed correctly that you need to use `map`.

map invokes on an array and return the result of a callback on each item.

We know that each comment looks like this

```json
 {
        id: 0,
        rating: 5,
        comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        author: "John Lemon",
        date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
 }
```

Meaning we need to return something similar to

```html
 <div className="comment">
      <div>{comment.comment}</div>
      <div>{comment.author}</div>
      <div>{comment.date}</div>
 </div>
```

Now let's do it with `map`:

```js
comments.map(function(comment) {
   return (
      <div className="comment">
        <div>{comment.comment}</div>
        <div>{comment.author}</div>
        <div>{comment.date}</div>
      </div>
  )}
)
```

This will produce the array:

```js
[
 <div className="comment">
      <div>{comment1.comment}</div>
      <div>{comment1.author}</div>
      <div>{comment1.date}</div>
 </div>,
 <div className="comment">
      <div>{comment2.comment}</div>
      <div>{comment2.author}</div>
      <div>{comment2.date}</div>
 </div>,
 <div className="comment">
      <div>{comment3.comment}</div>
      <div>{comment3.author}</div>
      <div>{comment3.date}</div>
 </div>
...
]
```